# Wordpress - Edit dashboard based on user id NOT user role

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Is there a way to edit the dashboard based on the user ID? I know this is relatively straight forward when targeting a user role, but how about ID?

For a working example, something along the lines of changing the admin menu background color for the user ID of 7.

The general goal is that I want to have 2 super admins that control the multisite although one of the super admins has little experience in wordpress so Im trying to style the admin to a very very basic set up while leaving my super-admin role untouched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this it completely possible. Take a look at the [actions run during an Admin page request](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference#Actions_Run_During_an_Admin_Page_Request).

You'll notice that the current user is authenticated and validated *before* the admin menus are rendered. You could just wrap whatever you want to hide in a conditional. For example:

```
if ( get_current_user_id() == 7 ) {
    // Change the admin bar background by loading a stylesheet
}
```